# How to insert a newline in printing list in itertools

Tags: python, text

I am permuting a few list. How to print the result in a newline?

Code:

```
import itertools

s=[ [ '1', '2','3'], ['a','b'],
['4','5','6','7'],
    ['f','g','e','y']]

print (list(itertools.product(*s,)))
```

Need Result:

```
#-- with a newline

1 a 4 f 
1 a 4 g 
1 a 4 e 
1 a 4 y
```

Current Result:

```
#-- not very readable

[('1', 'a', '4', 'f'), ('1', 'a', '4', 'g'), ('1', 'a', '4', 'e'), ('1', 'a', '4', 'y')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpack the tuples to f-strings, and join them all using `\n` as a separator.

```
import itertools

s=[ ['1', '2','3'], 
    ['a','b'],
    ['4','5','6','7'],
    ['f','g','e','y'] ]

print('\n'.join((f'{a} {b} {c} {d}' for a,b,c,d in itertools.product(*s,))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Unpack in print just like you already do in product...

```
for p in itertools.product(*s):
    print(*p)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to a dataframe and then call `to_string()`

```py
import pandas as pd
import itertools
s=[ [ '1', '2','3'], ['a','b'],
['4','5','6','7'],
    ['f','g','e','y']]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(*s,)))

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

If you don't want the columns at the top do this

```py
_, s = df.to_string(index=False).split('\n', 1)
print(s)
```